# Declare an array of structs whose content conforms to View protocol

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

Prefix: I'm a newbie regarding Generics in Swift. That's why the following problem and the resulting compiler messages are hard to understand for me.

Working with SwiftUI, I made a struct 'AlignedForm' that should use an Array to hold several 'AlignedFormRow' structs. These AlignedFormRows consist of a text label on the right and an arbitrary view on the left. They are implemented as a generic type like this:

```
struct AlignedFormRow<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let content: Content
    let title: String
    let titleWidth: CGFloat

    init(_ title: String, titleWidth: CGFloat, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.title = title
        self.titleWidth = titleWidth
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(title).frame(width: titleWidth, alignment: .trailing)
            content
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I can create content for my form rows in nice SwiftUI-style like this:

```
VStack {
    AlignedFormRow("Full Name", titleWidth:100.0) {
        TextField("your name", text: $name)
    }
    AlignedFormRow("Email", titleWidth:100.0) {
        TextField("your email", text: $email)
    }
}
```

Which results in two aligned labelled text fields:
[image: two aligned and labelled text fields]

So far it works fine. Now, I would like to create a helper struct "AlignedForm" that manages the titleWidth for all rows. But when I try to implement AlignedForm, I'm running into problems declaring a 'rows' Array:

```
struct AlignedForm {
    let rows: [AlignedFormRow<Content: View>]
}
```

The code doesn't compile and the compiler responds to that line with "Expected '>' to complete generic argument list" which doesn't make much sense to me. I blindly tried many different ways to declare this rows array, but it never compiles. What's the correct syntax here? Or is this approach flawed otherwise?

Comment: Generics do not work that way. You need either to use concrete type, like `AlignedFormRow<MyView>` or create those instances in-place, in `body`, by row data (like `ForEach` works). Second way is far preferable.

Comment: So, by that you mean it is not possible to declare an array like Array<AlignedFormRow<object-that-conforms-to-View>>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you wrote `AlignedFormRow<Content: View>`.
First you need to create a struct that conforms to View protocol, then use it in the declaration. Like,

```
struct AlignedFormView: View {
    var body: some View {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Then, use it in your array.

```
struct AlignedForm {
    let rows: [AlignedFormRow<AlignedFormView>]
}
```

This is the way. Thank you

Comment: Because I tried to do it SwiftUI-style by using @ViewBuilder (I edited my post to show how AlignedFormRows are created). That's the reason for the AlignedFormRow<Content: View> generic.

Comment: When you want to return multiple view, you need to use @ViewBuilder .

In your code, you wanted to declare an array of AlignedFormRow. But, you did not provide it. You just said <Content: View>. You have already did this, when create it `where Content: View`.

So, the problem is, think you make a bag and labeled it to contain tea leafs. And now you want to make a container and put several bags in it. Now, you can not just put empty bag in the container as there is no leaf there and labeled it again to contain tea leafs. You have already did it in the first place.

Comment: Now, you need put tea leafs in the bag and put bags in the container.

Just like this, you need to make a view and create AlignedFormRow with that and then put them in the array.

Comment: Thanks, that analogy helped me. I was under the impression I could declare an array of "identical bags of different sorts of tea leaves", but that's probably still a heterogeneous array.